# AWS MobileAnalyticsManager access to folder 'AWS Mobile Services\M4SP' is denied

Tags: event-log, access-denied, amazon-mobile-analytics

I am trying to add the AWSSDK DLL into my C# code to collect my event data and pass the data to the AWS bucket. My C# code is created with VS Share point template. The project contains WSP files. The following code indicates how I use the AWSSDK :

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentity;
using Amazon.MobileAnalytics.MobileAnalyticsManager;

CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(
                      "us-east-1:xxxxxx",//PoolID                       
                       RegionEndpoint.USEast1
                      );
Amazon.AWSConfigs.ApplicationName = "M4SP";
AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogMetrics = true;
AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogResponses = ResponseLoggingOption.Always;
AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig.LogMetricsFormat = LogMetricsFormatOption.JSON;
MobileAnalyticsManager manager = MobileAnalyticsManager.GetOrCreateInstance(                        
                      "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",//AppID
                        credentials,
                        RegionEndpoint.USEast1 // Region
                    );
CustomEvent customEvent = new CustomEvent("TestRecordEvent");
customEvent.AddAttribute("label", "M4SP");
customEvent.AddAttribute("action", "invoke");
customEvent.AddAttribute("details", "run the workflow test");
manager.RecordEvent(customEvent);
```

I found the code inside AWSSDK DLL was trying to log the data to local folder before passing it to AWS database. The location of the folder is `C:\Users\[userid]\AppData\Roaming\AWS Mobile Services`.
There is no problem in a standalone project since it always uses current user’s identity to run the application so it has access to the folder. But,  because of the authentication mechanism of SharePoint solutions, it uses Application Pool Identity to access the folder and it gets access denied issue and the whole process fails. 
Here is the error:

`"Access to the path 'AWS Mobile Services\M4SP' is denied."`

I modified the access right of Share point Application Pool Identity (in my case, it is “network service” account) but it still can’t access the folder .

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Thanks very much for the help!!